# How to pass multiple command in os.popen

Tags: python, python-3.x

Anyone can help me that how to pass two commands in Popen function

I have to pass following two command to be executed in cmd console

1. `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=kumawat_infinity key=123456789a`
2. `NETSH WLAN start hostednetwork`

These command will enable hotspot in window.

```py
import os

os.popen('netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=kumawat_infinity  key=123456789a')

os.popen('NETSH WLAN start hostednetwork')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put both your commands in the same string, separated by a semicolon. This is the function of the semicolon in the bash programming language.

Example:

```
os.popen(
    'netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=kumawat_infinity  key=123456789a; netsh wlan start hostednetwork'
)
```

Comment: Bro... this is not giving any error but command not executing one by one..

Comment: Can you be more specific what the problem is? I don't know what exactly `netsh` does, but this general idea worked on my machine when I tested it with basic `echo` and `ls` commands.